# Spark - How to do conditional reducing by key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, reduce

I have a DataFrame with two columns (key, value) as follow:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|         key|               value|
+------------+--------------------+
|[sid2, sid5]|             value1 |
|      [sid2]|             value2 |
|      [sid6]|             value3 |
+------------+--------------------+
```

The key is a Set of strings and I want to apply reduceByKey transformation where two keys are equal if there is an intersection between them, and the output should look like this:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|         key|               value|
+------------+--------------------+
|[sid2, sid5]|   [value1, value2] |
|      [sid6]|             value3 |
+------------+--------------------+
```

I tried to use a case class as a key wapper and overrode equals and hashCode functions but it didn't work ([SPARK-2620](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620)).

Any idea how to do it?
thanks in advance.

Update - DataFrame schema:

```
root
 |-- id1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- events1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- touchPoint: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- result: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- onlineId: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- clientId: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- newUser: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- userAgent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pageType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- clientIP: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Cartesian product solution on 100000 rows DataFrame it took a lot of time to be processed so that I decided to use graph [GraphFrame](https://graphframes.github.io), It is straightforward to compute connected components of a graph in linear time (in terms of the numbers of the vertices and edges of the graph).

- create vertices and edges DataFrames.
- build the graph.
- find connected components.

The final result looks like:

```
+------------+------+----------
|         key| value|component
+------------+------+----------
|      [sid5]|value1|component1
|      [sid2]|value2|component1
|      [sid6]|value3|component2
+------------+------+-----------
```

Then groupBy("component")

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot solved with `reduceByKey` because problem definition is not suitable for `byKey` transformations. The core requirement is that keys have well defined identity, however this is not the case here.

Consider dataset where we have keys `[sid2, sid4, sid5]` and `[sid2, sid3, sid5]`. In that case there is no way to uniquely assign objects to partitions. Overriding hash codes won't help you at all.

To make it worse, the problem in general case is distributed. Consider a set of set, such as for each set there is at least one other set with non-empty intersection. In that case all values should be merged into a single "cluster".

Overall - this is not a good problem for Spark without rather strict restriction, and cannot be solved with basic `byKey` transformations at all.

Inefficient solution, which might partially address you problem is to use Cartesian product:

```
rdd.cartesian(rdd)
  .filter { case ((k1, _), (k2, _)) => intersects(v1, v2) }
  .map { case ((k, _), (_, v)) => (k, v) }
  .groupByKey
  .mapValues(_.flatten.toSet)
```

this is however inefficient and doesn't address ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

That I think is doable using Spark SQL's Dataset API (and turned out a direct translation of the RDD-based solution of @user9003280).

```
// the dataset
val kvs = Seq(
  (Seq("sid2", "sid5"), "value1"),
  (Seq("sid2"), "value2"),
  (Seq("sid6"), "value3")).toDF("key", "value")
scala> kvs.show
+------------+------+
|         key| value|
+------------+------+
|[sid2, sid5]|value1|
|      [sid2]|value2|
|      [sid6]|value3|
+------------+------+

val intersect = udf { (ss: Seq[String], ts: Seq[String]) => ss intersect ts }
val solution = kvs.as("left")
  .join(kvs.as("right"))
  .where(size(intersect($"left.key", $"right.key")) > 0)
  .select($"left.key", $"right.value")
  .groupBy("key")
  .agg(collect_set("value") as "values")
  .dropDuplicates("values")
scala> solution.show
+------------+----------------+
|         key|          values|
+------------+----------------+
|      [sid6]|        [value3]|
|[sid2, sid5]|[value2, value1]|
+------------+----------------+
```